# Como usar SBT 0.12 e 0.13 ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: sbt

Eu tenho o *SBT 0.12* instalado em meu computador, com vários *plugins* globais, mas tenho visto vários projetos que já estão usando o `SBT 0.13`. Como posso fazer para ter ambos na minha máquina ao mesmo tempo, sem conflitos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No arquivo `project/build.properties` você pode adicionar uma linha com a versão do sbt desejada.

```
sbt.version=0.12.0
```

Assim você pode instalar a versão mais recente do sbt porém manter a compatibilidade dos projetos que usam uma versão anterior.

Fonte: [Hello, Word - sbt Documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Hello.html)

Comment: Infelizmente não funciona. Eu recebo uma mensagem de erro "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class jline.Terminal, but interface was expected".

Comment: Você está com a versão 13 instalada e setando a 12 no projeto ou ao contrário? (Tente o primeiro cenário, versão mais recente instalada e versão antiga sendo setada no properties)